# Write JSON into a field using Talend Open Studio

Tags: json, talend

I try to migrate data an old database into our new application.

In process, I need to grab data from old db to create a JSON which must be stored in a field in the new MySQL db.

So I use the components `tWriteJSONField` and `tExtractJSONFields`.

In `tWriteJSONField`, my XML tree looks like this :

```
path
|-- id [loop element]
|-- name
|-- description
```

*N.B. : I can't find how to use `loop element` and `group element` properties. I don't understand how it works and the documentation doesn't talk about this.*

The component `tWriteJSONField` is linked to a `tExtractJSONFields` in order to extract `id` from JSON. I need this to know to each record JSON must be linked.

`tExtractJSONFields` configuration : **XPath request**

```
"/path"
```

`tExtractJSONFields` configuration : **Mapping**

```
-----------------------------------------------
| column        | XPath request | get nodes ? |
-----------------------------------------------
| idForm        | "id"          | false       |
-----------------------------------------------
| jsonStructure | "*"           | yes         |
-----------------------------------------------
```

My problem is in `jsonStructure` output by `tExtractJSONField`, I only get the first child of my root tag. In my case `jsonStructure` looks like this :

```
{
   "id": "123"
}
```

Expected result is :

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "name": "Test",
   "description": "Test"
}
```

If I declare the child `name` before `id` for example, I will get :

```
{
   "name": "Test"
}
```

I have tried to change  the XPath query for `jsonStructure` but I never get all the fields.

Why ?

It's my first question about Talend, so if it lacks information, let me know in the comments.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT :**

Data from `tMysqlInput` to `tWriteJSONField` :

*N.B. : My flux contains more columns but I only show you which are used to create JSON.*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| IdForm | NomForm                    | DescrForm                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | English training           | <p>This is a description of the training</p>  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | French training            | <p>This contains HTML tags from a WYSIWYG</p> |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3      | How to use the application | <p>Description</p>                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In `tWriteJSONField`, columns are mapped to the JSON like this :

```
path
|-- id [loop element] --> IdForm
|-- name              --> NomForm
|-- description       --> DescrForm
```

`tWriteJSONField` output a new flux with the same columns as the input (although, this columns are all empty in the output even if they were populated in input) and add a new one `jsonStructure` which contains generated JSON.

This new flux is caught by a `tExtractJSONFields` (configuration for this component is available in my original post).

`tExtractJSONFields` outputs this flux :

```
--------------------------
| IdForm | jsonStructure |
--------------------------
| 1      | { "id": "1" } |
--------------------------
| 2      | { "id": "2" } |
--------------------------
| 3      | { "id": "3" } |
--------------------------
```

And I expect it returns this one :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| IdForm | jsonStructure                                                                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | { "id": "1", "name": "English training", "description": "<p>This is[...]</p>" } |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2      | { "id": "2", "name": "French training", "description": "<p>[...]</p>" }         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3      | { "id": "3", "name": "How to use the [...]", "description": "<p>[...]</p>" }    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT 2**

I use TOS 5.4.0.r110020 if it can help.

Comment: wow! that's difficult to answer without testing. Can you provide a sample of your out JSON and of your input data? With fake data, ofc. And please be patient for a couple of hours! ;)

Comment: Thanks for help. I have edited my post to add more details. Hope it's sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your XPath request for JSONStructure column is not correct. Just remove "*" and you will get the expected result.

[image: XPathQuery]

Also, if you don't need the root node in the json entry, just check "Remove root node" on tWriteJsonField and change Loop XPath Query to "/" in tExtractJSONFields

[image: Remove Root Node on tExtractJSONFields]

Comment: Thanks. I spent lots of my time on this sh**.